solana-cli with cold wallet
I was wondering if solana-cli had support with hardware wallets other than the ledger nano. I couldn't find anything online about how to sign transactions with other wallets using cli. Thank you for any help

There's only ledger support at the moment, but here's a PR for Trezor support: https://github.com/anza-xyz/agave/pull/306
